# How can I set the terminal encoding when running a crontab job?

Tags: bash, encoding, ruby, crontab, utf-8

I have a crontab job which executes a Ruby script on Arch Linux. It works basically, but when I call "googlecl" to post to my blog, it always shows a "safeDecodeError" exception (eg.: googlecl.SafeDecodeError: ascii could not decode 'Vas\xc3\xa1rnap'), because the command line I use contains national hungarian characters (éáüö, etc). My locale is set hu_HU.UTF-8 by command:

```
sudo localectl set-locale LANG="hu_HU.UTF-8"
```

My crontab line looks like:

```
05 15 * * * export LANG="hu_HU.UTF-8"; export LC_CTYPE="hu_HU.UTF-8"; /home/walaki/dl/musor-blogger
```

My Ruby script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'pry'

reklam=["http://keresztenytars.net","http://premium-leechers.blogspot.hu"]

fname="/home/walaki/util/radiomusor-blogger.txt"
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
if ARGV.length==0 then 
 date_today=Time.now.to_s.split(" ")[0]
else
 date_today=ARGV[0]
end 

url="http://hangtar.radio.hu/kossuth#!#"+date_today
datepart=date_today.gsub("-","")
dow=Date.parse(date_today).strftime("%A")
 case dow
     when /monday/i
      nap="Hétfő"
     when /tuesday/i
      nap="Kedd"
     when /wednesday/i
      nap="Szerda"
     when /thursday/i
      nap="Csütörtök"
     when /friday/i
      nap="Péntek"
     when /saturday/i
      nap="Szombat"
     when /sunday/i
      nap="Vasárnap"
 end

puts url
puts nap
puts datepart
b.goto url
b.links(:text=>"Részletes műsor")[0].click
sleep 6
#html="";b.divs(:class=>"musorelem sclick").each{|d| d.click rescue nil;html+=b.html}
html=b.html
tc=html.scan(/class\=\"me_idopont.*?\<span\>(.*?)\<\/span\>.*?\<div.*?class\=\"me_cim.*?\<span\>(.*?)\<\/span\>.*?\<div.*?class\=\"me_leiras.*?\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/m).flatten
h={};for i in 0..(tc.length-1)/3; h.merge!(tc[i*3]=>[tc[i*3+1],tc[i*3+2]]);end

   open(fname, 'w') { |f|
          f.puts "<div class='post-body entry-content' itemprop='articleBody'>"
          f.puts "<b>"+nap+"</b><br>"
          h.each do |k,v|
            #line="<a href=http://stream001.radio.hu:443/stream/"+datepart+"_"+k.gsub(":","")+"00_1.mp3>"+k+" "+v[0]+"</a><br><p style='margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px; text-align:justify; line-height:10px'><small>"+v[1].gsub("<br>","\n")+"</small></p>"
            line="<a href=http://stream001.radio.hu:443/stream/#{datepart}_#{k.gsub(":","")}00_1.mp3>#{k}</a> <a href='#{reklam.sample(1).first}' target=_blank>#{v[0]}</a><br><p style='margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px; text-align:justify; line-height:10px'><small>#{v[1].gsub("<br>","\n")}</small></p>"
            #binding.pry
            #puts line
            f.puts line
          end
         f.puts "</div>"
        }


var='google blogger post --blog="My Blog" --tags="'+nap+'" --title="'+date_today+', '+nap+'" --src=/home/walaki/util/radiomusor-blogger.txt'

system var
```

When I call the googlecl command with Ruby's "system" statement, the command line (var) contains UTF-8 characters (áéüö, etc) and googlecl throw an exception.

When I call my Ruby script from the usual terminal window manually, it works perfectly. But when I use crontab to start it daily, it always fails due to this terminal character encoding issue.

My question is how can I set the terminal character encoding when running the cron job?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to try:

- Make sure you re-export LANG and other environment variables for your subshell to make sure the "google" command sees them too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301294/shell-out-from-ruby-while-setting-an-environment-variable

- Encode the day-of-week strings ("nap") with HTML codes (&#n;) since they're going to the web anyway:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML

Comment: Thx, I have already tried the second method, but the googlecl command line tool escapes the string some way and the special characters "&#" appears on the webpage.

Comment: Methods for setting environment variables on the abovementioned page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301294/shell-out-from-ruby-while-setting-an-environment-variable) also doesn't work. There is something difference between the crontab shell and the normal shell which causes this annoyance.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for this post: http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/issues/detail?id=360